# Expandable widget in sliver list expands to the top instead of to the bottom due to center key

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to make expandable item in sliver list, but when the expandable widget is in sliver list above the sliver list with center key, expandable item expands to the top instead to the bottom.

```
CustomScrollView(
        center: _centerKey,
        slivers: [
// in this sliver list expandable expands to the top
          SliverList(
              delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
            buildItems(1),
          )),
          SliverList(
// in this sliver list expandable expands to the bottom
              key: _centerKey,
              delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
                buildItems(2),
              )),
// in this sliver list expandable expands also to the bottom
          SliverList(
              delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
            buildItems(3),
          )),
        ],
      );
```

in buildItems are basic Containers and one Expandable Widget from
https://pub.dev/packages/expandable

```
List<Widget> buildItems(int listIndex) {
      final items = <Widget>[];
      for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if (i == 5) {
// Expandable widget
          items.add(const ExpandedItem());
        } else {
          items.add(Container(
            width: double.infinity,
            height: 200,
            color: (i % 2 == 0) ? Colors.blue : Colors.red,
          ));
        }
      }

      return items;
    }
```

After clicking on yellow item, item goes to the top instead of stay at the same place (orange and brown are expanded content)

[image: after clicking on yellow item, item goes to the top instead of stay at the same place (oragne and brown are expanded content)]

```
class ExpandedItem extends StatefulWidget {
  const ExpandedItem({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ExpandedItem> createState() => _ExpandedItemState();
}

class _ExpandedItemState extends State<ExpandedItem> {
  final controller = ExpandableController();
  List<Widget> buildItems() {
    final items = <Widget>[];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      items.add(GestureDetector(
        onTap: i == 9
            ? () {
                controller.toggle();
              }
            : null,
        child: Container(
          width: double.infinity,
          height: 100,
          color: (i % 2 == 0) ? Colors.orange : Colors.brown,
        ),
      ));
    }

    return items;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        ExpandableNotifier(
          controller: controller,
          child: Expandable(
            collapsed: GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                controller.toggle();
              },
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.yellow,
                width: double.infinity,
                height: 100,
              ),
            ),
            expanded: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: [
                Container(
                  color: Colors.yellow,
                  width: double.infinity,
                  height: 100,
                ),
                ...buildItems()
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by expandable item expands to the top instead to the bottom. Can you share an image?

Comment: I add a gif to the question for better understanding

Comment: ExpandedItem() show me this customWIdget

Comment: I added it to the bottom of the asnwer

Comment: when I click on the yellow. it doesn't go to the top but instead it expand to bottom by staying there, in my case

Comment: show me your key value in your case _centerKey

Comment: final Key _centerKey = UniqueKey();

Comment: try the code below

Comment: it depends where the Expanded is, if it is in the sliver with centerKey, it expands to bottom. If it is in the sliver above, it expands to top.

Answer (score 1):

check this when the yellow is tapped, it expand downward

```
class _ShowCaseState extends State<ShowCase> {
  final Key _centerKey = const ValueKey<String>('bottom-sliver-list');

  List<Widget> buildItems(int listIndex) {
    final items = <Widget>[];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      if (i == 5) {
        items.add(const ExpandedItem());
      } else {
        items.add(Container(
          width: double.infinity,
          height: 200,
          color: (i % 2 == 0) ? Colors.blue : Colors.red,
        ));
      }
    }

    return items;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: CustomScrollView(
      center: _centerKey,
      slivers: [
// in this sliver list expandable expands to the top
        SliverList(
            key: _centerKey, //here
            delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
          buildItems(1),
        )),
        SliverList(
// in this sliver list expandable expands to the bottom
            delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
              buildItems(2),
            )),
// in this sliver list expandable expands also to the bottom
        SliverList(
            delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
          buildItems(3),
        )),
      ],
    ));
  }
}

class ExpandedItem extends StatefulWidget {
  const ExpandedItem({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ExpandedItem> createState() => _ExpandedItemState();
}

class _ExpandedItemState extends State<ExpandedItem> {
  final controller = ExpandableController();
  List<Widget> buildItems() {
    final items = <Widget>[];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      items.add(GestureDetector(
        onTap: i == 9
            ? () {
                controller.toggle();
              }
            : null,
        child: Container(
          width: double.infinity,
          height: 100,
          color: (i % 2 == 0) ? Colors.orange : Colors.brown,
        ),
      ));
    }

    return items;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        ExpandableNotifier(
          controller: controller,
          child: Expandable(
            collapsed: GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                controller.toggle();
              },
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.yellow,
                width: double.infinity,
                height: 100,
              ),
            ),
            expanded: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: [
                Container(
                  color: Colors.yellow,
                  width: double.infinity,
                  height: 100,
                ),
                ...buildItems()
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, but i have to keep centerKey only in the middle SliverList.

Comment: Sorry, you have it only in middle sliver list. What you have changed? Works it even you tap yellow widget in first sliver?

Comment: even I moved  centerKey to the first sliver, it works like you wanted. check the edited code

Comment: but you cannot move it, I need it in second sliver

Comment: you only need expanded in the second yellow bar?